# Лист пользователей через embed

Tags: sqlite3, discord.py

Делаю список пользователей по указанному параметру в базе данных

```
async def __sk(ctx, frac: int = None, dos: int = None):
  if frac is None:
      for value in sql.execute(f"SELECT idds, dostup FROM users"):
          name, dostup = value
          member = bot.get_user(name)
          print(member) 
          await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(description=f" Пользователь {member.mention} | Доступ - {dostup}"))
  else:
      if dos is None:
          for value in sql.execute(f"SELECT idds, dostup FROM users WHERE frac = {frac}"):
              name, dostup = value
              member = bot.get_user(name)
              print(member)
              await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(description=f" Пользователь {member.mention} | Доступ - {dostup}"))
      else:
          for value in sql.execute(f"SELECT idds, dostup FROM users WHERE frac = {frac} AND dostup = {dos}"):
              name, dostup = value
              member = bot.get_user(name)
              print(member)
              await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(description=f" Пользователь {member.mention} | Доступ - {dostup}"))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно строчки вывести в один embed?

Comment: у `discord.Embed` есть метод `add_field()`

Comment: Смотри, выводятся столько enbed, сколько есть пользователей. а хочу чтобы все в один было

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте создать список, назовите его к примеру `member_list` и с помощью метода member_list.append() добавляйте в список новых пользователей.

```
for value in sql.execute(f"SELECT idds, dostup FROM users"):
          name, dostup = value
          member_list = []
          member = bot.get_user(name)
          member_list.append(member)
          member_list.append(\n)
```

После цикла просто выведите список.